# Displaying on-image instagram tags

Tags: image, tags, instagram

Can I display the on-image (tooltip type) tags created by users through the IG api on images? The basic tags/{tag-name} isn't the answer for specific on image tags.

Comment: are u talking about `user` tags on images (not hashtags)? like this? http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/900635430205440533_55431

Comment: Yes. User tags on the image.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The API returns `users_in_photos` in json response for any media that has user tags, it has user details and position of tagged location in photo:

```
 "users_in_photo": [{
    "user": {
        "username": "kevin",
        "full_name": "Kevin S",
        "id": "3",
        "profile_picture": "..."
    },
    "position": {
        "x": 0.315,
        "y": 0.9111
    }
}],
```

multiply the position.x and position.y by the width of image you are displaying, that is the pixel offset of tagged location on the photo. create a tooltip css and display the username there, here is example: http://gramfeed.com/instagram/900635430205440533_55431

Comment: Thank you very much. Most helpful.